# Is it require to justify something that is obvious?

Tags: calculus

Im thinking of for instance: suppose we have a sum $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k f(k) $ Then, certainly $\sum (-1)^k f(k) \leq \sum f(k) $

Can we take results of this type as granted? or do we need to verify such claims?

Comment: which is equivalent to $\sum (-1)^k f(k) \geq - \sum f(k) $

Comment: The inequlaity is simply false unless there is some additional assumption on $f(k)$.

Comment: Kavi, can you explain the downvote?

Comment: I assume you have in mind $f(k)\geq 0$ for all $k$. Then it is true and rather trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inequality is false if, for example, all the values of $\;f\;$ at odd values of $\;k\;$ are negative and all the values of $\;f\;$ at even values of $\;f\;$ at even values of $\;k\;$ are positive...

We have to be careful with the word "obvious" in mathematics, and if something's obvious then not only we must be able to prove it but we have to do it very easily...and again: "easily" depends on who's talking.

Comment: I meant $f(k) \geq 0$ :/

Comment: @James If you omit the only hypothesis on $f(k)$ when you type the qustion it is very likely to attract downvotes.

Comment: @Kavi you have downvoted 1425 times and only 881 upvotes! Be nice!

Comment: Thank you for the response DonAntonio!!!